# When will be NbAuthJWTToken expired in Nebular?

Tags: nestjs, nebular

In backend I've made by nestjs, jwt token is expired in 30s after created.

but frontend is still not loging out.

I dont know when will be NbAuthJWTToken expired.

Comment: welcome to so, you need to show your code in your for other to help, I would suggest to read [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do you mean when you refresh the page doesn't log out or when  the frontend doesn't check if the token without refreshing the page